# Can someone explain to me step-by-step how to solve following expression?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Expression goes like this:
$\frac{(5-2i)-(3+4i)}{(5+2i)+(3-4i)}$

In fact, I already know the answer which is $\frac{7-11i}{17}$

I tried one method of solving which was performing all of adding and substracting, then multiplying numerator and denominator by conjugated denominator but still couldn't manage to get the same result. So, I'm asking for step-by-step solution to see where exactly I'm making an error.

Comment: That's not an equation; there's no equality sign, it's just an expression.

Comment: First of all, that's not an equation. You're simplifying an expression. Second of all, please show your exact work since what you describe should've led you to the right answer.

Comment: Add as you said and divide numerator and denominator by $2$. You get $\frac{1-3i}{4-i}$. Multiply numerator and denominator by $4+i$ and get $\frac{(1-3i)(4+i)}{4^2+1}=\frac{7-11i}{17}$.

Comment: @arts Please make that an answer so the question can be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an equation. It is just a term.

We have $\frac{5-2i-3-4i}{5+2i+3-4i}=\frac{2-6i}{8-2i}$. Now we factor out $2$. And get

$\frac{1-3i}{4-i}$. Extend with $\overline{4-i}=4+i$ and we obtain:

$\frac{(1-3i)(4+i)}{4^2+1}=\frac{4+i-12i+3}{17}=\frac{7-11i}{17}$